# Why inner "template" class not allowed inside function?

Tags: c++, templates, inner-classes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can't templates be declared in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3449112/why-cant-templates-be-declared-in-a-function)

```
void fun ()
{
  template<typename T> struct InnerClass {};
}
```

gives errors.

```
error: expected primary-expression before ‘template’
error: expected ‘;’ before ‘template’
```

**Just** wanted to know, **WHY** ?

Comment: Same question: [Why can't templates be declared in a function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3449112/why-cant-templates-be-declared-in-a-function)