# Template alias scope

Tags: c++, template-aliases

As per http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias, aliases are block-level declarations. It doesn't say anything special about template aliases, so it should be read that template aliases are block-level declarations as well.

However, it is impossible to use template aliases at block level. The errors are different depending on the compiler - while g++ gives a meaningful message, saying that templates are not allowed at block scope, clang is completely cryptic. (example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0f0862dad6f3da61).

Questions I have so far:

- Does cppreference fail to specify that template aliases can not be used at block scope? (Or do I need to take a reading course?)
- Are the compilers correct in denying template aliases on block level (the feature I find very interesting for my particular coding habits)
- If the answer to the second is Yes, what might be the rationale for this? Why would compiler deny me this pure syntax sugar?

Comment: Re "pure syntax sugar", no that's not so. However, I'm just out of bed and my neurons haven't yet engaged fully. Others will have to elaborate.

Answer (score 6):

An alias template is [temp.alias]

> A template-declaration in which the declaration is an alias-declaration (Clause 7) declares the identifier to
>   be a alias template. An alias template is a name for a family of types. The name of the alias template is a
>   template-name.

And if we look at 14.2 [temp] we have

> A template-declaration can appear only as a namespace scope or class scope declaration. In a function
>   template declaration, the last component of the declarator-id shall not be a template-id.

So yes cppreference is off saying that it can be declared at block scope and your compilers are correct.  If you do click on the link of [block declarations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/declarations) It will bring you to a list of declarations and in that it has [Template declaration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/templates) and in there it has

> declaration of a class (including struct and union), a member class or member enumeration type, a function or member function, a static data member at namespace scope, a variable or static data member at class scope, (since C++14) or an alias template (since C++11) It may also define a template specialization.

As for why the standard says that templates can only be declared in namespace scope or class scope I like [James Kanze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/649665/james-kanze) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6032668/4342498)

> The problem is probably linked to the historical way templates were implemented: early implementation techniques (and some still used today) require all symbols in a template to have external linkage. (Instantiation is done by generating the equivalent code in a separate file.) And names defined inside a function never have linkage, and cannot be referred to outside of the scope in which they were defined.

Comment: Alright, compilers are behaving per standard. Now, do you know the answer to my last question?

Comment: @SergeyA What do you mean?  your last question is moot as we cannot declare templates at block scope.

Comment: Well, this is (even if branded so by standard) not a template declaration. It is template alias declaration, and there is a difference between those two. Again, I see templare alias a pure syntax sugar. What are the reasons to forbid it's declaration at block scope? What would it break if allowed?

Comment: @SergeyA No there is not a difference.  You still have to specify the type with a alias template.  Take `template<class T> using vec2d = std::vector<std::vector<T>>;` we would still have to specify the type when we use `vec2d` like `vec2d<int> foo;`  If you are using the template keyword then it is a template declaration.

Comment: This is fine. The question is, why is it prohibited. There should be a reason, like compilers can't cope with it, it would be unsafe, etc. Some reason. I do not see it. template <class T> using ve2d = std::vector<std:vector<T> > is just a shorthand. So whenever compiler sees ve2d<char> it can exapand it into std::vector<std::vector<char> > . I do not see why needs to be prohibited. And this is the question I am asking.

Comment: Sorry, can't accept it :) I understand why templates themselves can not be defined inside functions. But template aliases do not have to be treated this way. If I take James' answer and try to apply it to template alias scenario, I do not see how it breaks anything. Template does provide a template for code generation, and thus needs symbols. True. But alias does not! The template which is referred by this alias - yes. But not the alias itself!

Comment: @cubbi awesome.  Thank you.  I did not know people could edit/contribute to it.

Comment: @Cubbi, Hi :) Do you know the answer to my question by any chance? (and I hope you've recognized your former collegue in my face ;)

Answer (score 1):

The compilers are behaving correctly.

Section 14 of the C++14 standard:

> A template-declaration can appear only as a namespace scope or class
>   scope declaration.